# Re-numbering references

Tags: bibliographies, numbering

I have some references in my text, and I want them to be ordered such that the first reference is [1], the second is [2], and so on. But what I have is that the first reference is [3], the second is [1], and the third is [2]. How can I change the order so that they are numbered correctly, and the references appear in the order that they are cited?

The current bibliography style that I am using is `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`, and I am also using the `natbib` package.

Comment: assuming you are using bibtex or biblatex, most styles either number in order of appearance or alphabetical by author, just using the most basic `unsrt` style should do what you want.

Comment: Is there a way to do that while keeping the current style? I currently have `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`, which looks exactly how I want, except for the ordering.

Comment: natbib (which you didn't even mention in the original question) has unsrtnat as a version of unsrt just as it has plainnat which is a version of plain

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry about that. I've edited the question.

Comment: so is unsrtnat the answer?:-)

Answer (score 1):

plainnat (like plain) uses numerical references but orders in alphabetical order of author. you want unsrtnat which is a version of unsrt which doesn't sort at all so citations are numbered in order of appearance.